# SQL - counts and sum for different values of count and name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with results from various tournaments (only showing the relevant fields for this case):

name, lugar, id, formato

I need to do a table giving different values according to the number of players and their result.

name is the tournament name, lugar the place the player got, id the player identifier and formato its a tournament specific field.

quick example:

for formato = X, lugar  = 1 => 8 points if the sum of ids for name > 32.

I was trying to do with count and cases, searched but didn't find a suitable answer.

Maybe i should do separate tables ?

at this moment i have this that works to sum the points, but doesn't check the # of players of the formato.

```
SELECT name, id, ROUND((sum(pontos)/((sum(rondas)+sum(byes))*3)*100),2) as Performance, 
    sum(case 
              when lugar = '1' then 8 
              when lugar = '2' then 6
              when lugar > '2' AND  lugar < '5' then 4
              when lugar > '4' AND lugar < '9' then 2
              else null end)as Pontos
FROM players 
WHERE season='0' 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY `Pontos` DESC, `Performance` DESC
```

I've tried add an case with formato = 'X' then the sum but i got an sql error.

example populated table:

```
name    id  format  lugar
maio    1   STD 1
maio    2   STD 2
abril   1   STD 4
abril   3   STD 1
junho   1   MDR 5
junho   2   MDR 1
julho   3   MDR 2
julho   4   MDR 8
```

expect result with conditions:
 if format = STD, when lugar =  1, gives 8 points, lugar = 2 gives 6 points.
if format = MDR, when lugar = 1, gives 5 points, lugar = 2 gives 3 points
and if count id where format = STD greater than 3 (just and example) 1 extra point

And if count id where format = STD (example) the points that are given according the lugar would give different points.

so, with that populated table it would give something like:

```
id  points  performance
1   17  50
2   10  40
3   4   60
4   1   40
```

(didn't check values, just example of the expected result).

There were the kind of conditions i would wnat to implement.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results in a tabular format.

Comment: is there an easy way to put data in tabular form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a nested `case when`:

```
  SELECT 
        name
        , id
        , ROUND((sum(pontos)/((sum(rondas)+sum(byes))*3)*100),2) as Performance, 
        sum(  case when formato ='X' THEN
             (case 
                when lugar = '1' then 8 
                when lugar = '2' then 6
                when lugar > '2' AND  lugar < '5' then 4
                when lugar > '4' AND lugar < '9' then 2
                else null end)
                END
      ) as Pontos
  FROM players 
  WHERE season='0' 
  GROUP BY dci 
  ORDER BY `Pontos` DESC, `Performance` DESC
```

and you can use different case for formato

```
  SELECT 
        name
        , id
        , ROUND((sum(pontos)/((sum(rondas)+sum(byes))*3)*100),2) as Performance, 
        sum(  case 
                when formato ='X' THEN
                 (case 
                    when lugar = '1' then 8 
                    when lugar = '2' then 6
                    when lugar > '2' AND  lugar < '5' then 4
                    when lugar > '4' AND lugar < '9' then 2
                    else null end)
                when formato = 'Y' THEN 100 END

                END
      ) as Pontos
  FROM players 
  WHERE season='0' 
  GROUP BY dci 
  ORDER BY `Pontos` DESC, `Performance` DESC
```

Comment: that's it, i've tried to add multiple cases but failled for some reason and thought it was not possible.

Thank you :)